# Using xpath with Firewatir

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir

I'm just starting out with ruby and firewatir, so I'm trying to find out if it's just me, or if something is broken with firewatir.

I'm trying to select an element using xpath.

This works:

```
browser.link(:id => "about").exists #true
```

This fails

```
browser.link(:xpath => "//*[@id='about']").exists #false
```

However, this works as well:

```
browser.element_by_xpath("//*[@id='about']").exists #true
```

This is on firewatir 1.7.1

```
$ ruby -v   #ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [i686-linux]
```

Comment: I have not used Ruby 1.9.2 with watir, but I didn't think it would affect something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there may be a bug with combining :xpath and multiple attributes, because that XPath query doesn't work for me either when I use :xpath =>:

```
irb(main):021:0> ff.link(:xpath => "//*[@id='about']").exists?
=> false
```

But it works if I use the single-attribute style (a comma instead of =>) to find the element, and use "exists?" with a question mark on the end.

Not sure why, but both "exists" and "exists?" are defined, and they have different behavior:

```
irb(main):018:0> ff.link(:xpath, "//*[@id='about']").exists?
=> true
irb(main):019:0> ff.link(:xpath, "//*[@id='about']").exists
=> ""
```